# how to synchronize countdown timer to all user

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, timer

I am developing a countdown timer app. User can register the app and share their own countdown timer; However, I have a problem here, how to let all user synchronize the same countdown timer? 
I use Angular and NodeJS + MongoDB to develop this app. 
My problem is the countdown timer is running by angularjs that only one user can see the running timer, but other people can't. Should I update every second number in database and query it every second or running timer in the backend?

any suggestion ?

Comment: Depending on how critical the timer is, you could query the database for the current value on page load and increment it locally

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it this way:  When the timable action occurs server-side, store both the start time **and** the end time in the database.  Upon page load, both numbers get pulled to the client, which figures out the delta and starts its own local countdown.   The GUI can optionally show the server-side end time, which is the "time of record."

Comment: End time and current time should be sufficient, especially when taking timezones into account.